# Bitwise shift makes my program halt?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, shift, halt

I am working with an assignment where I have to write a C function that calculates log2 of an unsigned integer *n* by finding the most significant set bit and returning the position of that bit. For example, if *n* is 17 (0b10001), the function should return 4.

Below is the code I have so far, but the bitwise operation makes the program halt. By commenting out the loop through line 6-9 the program works fine. I cannot for the life of me understand why it does that. Can someone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int mylog2(unsigned int n) {
    int log = 1;
    while (n != 1) {
        n >> 1;
        log++;
    }
    return log;
}


int main() {
    int a;
    a = mylog2(17);
    printf("%d", a);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `n >> 1;` -> `n >>= 1;`

Comment: The fact that your program halts might be a problem, but it's not the halting problem.

Comment: +1 @Mysticial.  And user167037, if you turn on some more warnings, you'll probably get something about "result of expression unused" for your original program.  `clang` warns by default, even.

Comment: Yup, I edited that to "halt" instead now.

Comment: There are many much faster ways to get log₂n in [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float). And your CPU is also highly likely to have a single instruction to do that. Check your compiler's intrinsic list

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop because you never change the value of n. Instead of `n >> 1;` use `n = n >> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your while loop. You do `n >> 1` but you never assign it.